# How to prevent caching in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, caching, meta-tags

I tried using a meta tag to the specific page where I want to stop caching and also tried adding caching in web config but it doesn't help. I used the following tags.

Used in webconfig:

```
<system.webServer>
<caching enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

Used in specific page:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: How did you determine it doesn't help? What headers does your browser receive?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are testing with firefox which does not check these meta tags. I had this problem as well and unfortunately you are not able to control caching behavior of firefox through code in your webpage (as far as I am aware since the last time I checked was two month ago).